# Get another data from PagingDataSource

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-paging, android-paging-3

I am building a movie app and I just finish implementing Paging.
Right now I can only get the popular movies from the PagingDataSource and my question is how can I get another set of data, for example: upcomming movies.

Do I need to create another paging source for every set of list or I can use the same one ?

Thank you!

This is my PagingDataSource:

```
private const val STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1

class MoviePagingDataSource(private var apiService: AbsoluteAPI) : PagingSource<Int,Movie>() {


    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Movie>): Int? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Movie> {

        val pagePosition = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX

            val response = apiService.fetchPopularMovies(apiKey,pagePosition)
            Log.e("Response","Result: {${response.body()}}")
            val movies = response.body()?.moviesResults ?: emptyList()

        return try {
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = movies,
                    prevKey = if (pagePosition == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else pagePosition - 1,
                    nextKey = if (movies.isEmpty()) null else pagePosition + 1
                )

            }catch (exception : HttpException){
                Log.e("exception","exception $exception")
                LoadResult.Error(exception)
            }catch (exception : IOException){
                Log.e("exception","exception $exception")
                LoadResult.Error(exception)
            }

    }


}
```